# Change tags in quill editor?

Tags: javascript, rich-text-editor, quill

I tried to look in the documentation but nothing explain how for example I could change the bold format to wrap text between `<strong>text</strong>` tag instead of `<b>text</b>` tag ?

```
var options = {
    modules: {
        placeholder: { text: attrs.rtePlaceholder, style: { color: '#A9A9A9' } }
    }
};
var quil = new Quill('#' + element.attr('id'), options);
var Normalizer = Quill.require('normalizer');
delete Normalizer.ALIASES["STRONG"];
Normalizer.ALIASES["B"] = "STRONG";
quil.addFormat('bold', { tag: 'STRONG', prepare: 'bold' });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official support is still forthcoming but this should work for now:

```
var Normalizer = Quill.require('normalizer');
delete Normalizer.ALIASES["STRONG"];
Normalizer.ALIASES["B"] = "STRONG";
quill.addFormat('bold', { tag: 'STRONG', prepare: 'bold' });
```

Comment: I doesnt work I updated my post with my code if it can help, thank you for helping me

Comment: Can you get rid of your placeholder module? The posted code works one the quilljs.com homepage.